Login user with user_login_finalize fails
Our site uses a SSO with a third party API which sends over the username/email address of a user, we then use that username/email to log the user in using the user_login_finalize function.
However, since upgrading our site to Drupal 10 this now sporadically fails and the user receives an Access denied error. There is no info in any of our log files and I can see that the required cookies are not being set in the browser.
I have tried to post data to our API endpoint directly via Postman and this also works and fails randomly.

Welcome to Drupal Answers! Unfortunately this website doesn't accept posts that ask multiple questions. In this post the questions are "Have there been any changes to this function?" and "Does anyone know a way to debug this function?". You should update the post to ask a single question. Additionally, "Does anyone know a way to debug this function?" isn't specific enough—many people know how to debug functions—and the answer may not require Drupal expertise. Additionally, the "debug" question may require a look at your code as the calling context may be the issue.

Thanks for editing the post but you do have to ask a question.

If the problem also occurs in Postman, aka without using Drupal, then the problem is more likely in the API endpoint. In that case you might better ask your question on StackOverflow.
